# Rails number_to_currency precision doesn't work - is it a bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionviewhelper, number-to-currency

I'm trying to use number_to_currency to get two digits after the decimal dot in Rails 3, but I can get only one. My DB field is defined like this:

```
t.decimal  "amount",              :precision => 5, :scale => 2
```

In my template I have:

```
#{number_to_currency(@purch.amount)}
```

And yet as the result I get: **PLN 34,7**
In the DB I can clearly see: **34.70**
I would like to see my second zero - is it a feature or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to check the following setting in one's locale configuration file:

```
  currency:
      format:
        strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be using a custom locale, try forcing the behavior you want by explicitly setting the options of number_to_currency:

```
number_to_currency(@purch.amount, :precision => 2)
```

You can also set these options in the locale file for your language. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: I have tried :precision and got no juice as well, thank you however to pointing me to the locale options, I have found I had **:strip_insignificant_zeros** set to true which is the answer to my problem. Thank you!